# how to post bootstrap tag-it input values in Laravel 5.4.12?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5.4, tag-it

i am working on Laravel project but little bit confused how to post tag-it multiple values to controller and how to save it separately in DB ?? these values will be saved in multiple rows(records) against single foreign key..

```html
<div class="form-group wish-tags">
 <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Wish to visit:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <input type="text" value="" data-role="tagsinput" id="tags" name="wish-tags" class="form-control">
     </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group wish-tags">
  <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Already visited:</label>
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <input type="text" value="" data-role="tagsinput" id="tags" name="visited-tags" class="form-control">
       </div>
</div>
```

Visitedlist Table

```
CREATE TABLE `visitedlist` (
`id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`locations` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `FK1_vistedlist_list` (`user_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK1_vistedlist_list` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

WishList Table

```
CREATE TABLE `wishlist` (
`id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`locations` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `FK1_wishList` (`user_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK1_wishList` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how the data is formatted, when you receive it in your controller method, you need to split it into individual items, loop over and save each of them.

So, let‘s you receive the items in your method as "item1,item2,item3", your code could look like this:

```
$locations = Request::input('wish-tags');

foreach (explode(",", $locations) as $location)
{
   $tag = new Tag();
   $tag->location = $location;
   $tag->user()->associate($theUser);
   $tag->save();
}
```

Hope that helps! If not feel free to leave a comment!

Comment: only last value of the input posted not multiple..why?

Comment: Sorry, but without the specific code parts (complete form, controller action, etc.) it is pretty difficult to find the reason for this. I would suggest, that you either update your opening post, or start a whole new question, because that seems to be a totally new problem.

Comment: can i edit this question if u don't mind ? and after edit u will be review it and solve my problem

Comment: I try my best, but can‘t promise anything. In my opinion, the best option would be to open up a new question, with all the necessary information and add the link to it here as a comment. That way I‘m notified about it and also you have a bigger chance to get your problem solved, because you will reach a larger audience.